# How to have only 1 space between a word and a counter

Tags: counters

I am using the following counter:

```
\newcounter{foo}
  \newcommand\num{
    \refstepcounter{foo}
      \thefoo.}
```

Two (2) spaces are automatically inserted between the preceding word and the counter -- e.g., `word \num` shows up in the pdf file as `word  1.`

Is there a way to have just one space between a word and a counter?  If possible, I'd like to avoid writing `word\num` and would prefer to write it like `word \num`

Comment: Use `%` at the end of line, e.g., `…\num{%` and `…foo}%`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comment out spurious blank spaces (one carriage return tantamounts to a blank space) in the definition:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{foo}
  \newcommand\num{%
    \refstepcounter{foo}%
      \thefoo.}

\begin{document}

a \num

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that works perfectly -- thank you very much!!!  :)